# Solution needed for the symptom of depending on macro expansion order

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expansion

**Context: TikZ**.  I often write commands like

```
\draw[->,line width=2mm] (3.3,4.3) -- (1.5,2.5) ;
```

in the context of a checkered board (that is not chess).  I want to replace these points by string coordinates like `f5`, `c5` such that I can just write `\arrow{f5,c5}`, which would expand to

```
\draw[->,line width=2mm] (5.5,5.5) -- (2.5,5.5) ;
```

since the `f` column is at horizontal distance `5.5` and the `c` column is at horizontal distance `2.5`.

**What have I tried**?  I tried putting a macro call in place of these coordinates, but TikZ complains that it cannot understand the coordinates.  It seems to me TikZ sees my macros there, not the expansion of them.  (I won't say I need to know how to expand things in a certain order because you probably have better ways to do everything.)

---

**UPDATE**: Here's a compilable document showing the board.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{printgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.2}

\def\labelstyle{\bf}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\innerboard}{\begingroup
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,6}
  \foreach \y in {1,2,...,6} { %% crazy code, watch out!
    \ifthenelse{\(\isodd{\x}\and\isodd{\y}\)\OR\(\not\(\isodd{\x}\)\and\not\(\isodd{\y}\)\)}{\filldraw[fill=printgray]}{\draw} (\x, \y) rectangle +(1,-1);
  }
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\alternatexfill}[1]{\ifthenelse{\not{\isodd{#1}}}{\filldraw[fill=printgray]}{\draw}}
\newcommand{\alternatefill}[1]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{#1}}{\filldraw[fill=printgray]}{\draw}}

\newcommand{\topborder}{\begingroup
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,6} {
  \alternatefill{\x} (\x, 6) +(0, 0.2) rectangle +(1, 1+0.2);
}
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\bottomborder}{\begingroup
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,6}
  \alternatexfill{\x} (\x, -1) +(0, -0.2) rectangle +(1, 1 - 0.2);
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\leftborder}{\begingroup
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,5}
  \alternatefill{\y} (0, \y) +(-0.2, 0) rectangle +(1 - 0.2,1);
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\rightborder}{\begingroup
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,5}
  \alternatexfill{\y} (7, \y) +(0.2, 0) rectangle +(1 + 0.2,1);
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\ring}{\begingroup
  \bottomborder
  \rightborder
  \topborder
  \leftborder
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\labelstop}{\begingroup
\def\pos{8}
\draw (0, \pos) +(0.3, -0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle a};
\foreach [count=\x] \c in {b,c, ..., g}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\label{\x + 1}
  \draw (\x, \pos) +(0.5, -0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle \c};
}
\draw (7, \pos) +(0.7, -0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle h};
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\labelsright}{\begingroup
\def\pos{8}
\draw (\pos, -1) +(0.5, 0.3) node {\strut\labelstyle 1};
\draw (\pos,  6) +(0.5, 0.7) node {\strut\labelstyle 8};
\foreach \x in {2,...,7}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xcoord{\x - 2}
  \draw (\pos,  \xcoord) +(0.5, 0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle \x};
}
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\labelsleft}{\begingroup
\def\pos{-0.2}
\draw (\pos, -1) +(-0.5, 0.3) node {\strut\labelstyle 1};
\draw (\pos,  6) +(-0.5, 0.7) node {\strut\labelstyle 8};
\foreach \x in {2,...,7}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xcoord{\x - 2}
  \draw (\pos,  \xcoord) +(-0.5, 0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle \x};
}
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\labelsbottom}{\begingroup
\def\pos{-1}
\draw (0, \pos) +(0.3, -0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle a};
\foreach [count=\x] \c in {b,c, ..., g}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\label{\x + 1}
  \draw (\x, \pos) +(0.5, -0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle \c};
}
\draw (7, \pos) +(0.7, -0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle h};
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\labels}{\labelsleft\labelsbottom\labelsright\labelstop}

\newcommand{\board}{
  \ring
  \innerboard
  \labels
  %% show origin
  \filldraw[fill=black] (0,0) circle [radius=1pt] +(0,-0.5) node{origin};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\ring
\board
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not clear how to translate the `5` in `f5`. Clearly `a` is mapped to `0.5`, `b` to `1.5`, and so on, but why should `5` become `7.5`?

Comment: Hi and welcome. If you gave the code of your chessboard and the code of your macro, it would be easier to understand.

Comment: @egreg, that was a typo on my part.  I fixed it to 5.5 (and not 7.5).  So the 5 in f5 is actually the height.

Comment: And therefore `f1` should be mapped to `(5.5,1.5)`? It doesn't seem consistent, I'd expect `(5.5,0.5)`. Is the board `8x8` or what?

Comment: why don't you name the coordinates instead of trying to convert the input to numbers?

Comment: Question updated showing a compilable document with the board.  The board is practically a 6x6 as the game happens in the inner board.  The outer ring isn't quite involved in the game.  It's coming to my attention now that perhaps the entire board (including the outer ring) should have began at (0,0), at the origin.  (I think I have been battling so much with learning TikZ and TeX that I might have neglected the problem domain.  Maybe you'll convince me to start from scratch.)  Thank you all.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't know any other way to specify coordinates.  So far the TikZ manual has only taught me about the syntax `(x,y)` possibly with increments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to name coordinates, you can do:

`\coordinate (⟨name⟩) at (⟨x⟩,⟨y⟩);`.

In the example below I introduced a macro `\introduceCoordinates` which does that for you by looping over the numbers 1..8 both for forming x-coordinates and for forming y-coordinates and for composing names like a1 or h8.

This might be a starting-point.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{printgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.2}

\def\labelstyle{\bf}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\innerboard}{\begingroup
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,6}
  \foreach \y in {1,2,...,6} { %% crazy code, watch out!
    \ifthenelse{\(\isodd{\x}\and\isodd{\y}\)\OR\(\not\(\isodd{\x}\)\and\not\(\isodd{\y}\)\)}{\filldraw[fill=printgray]}{\draw} (\x, \y) rectangle +(1,-1);
  }
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\alternatexfill}[1]{\ifthenelse{\not{\isodd{#1}}}{\filldraw[fill=printgray]}{\draw}}
\newcommand{\alternatefill}[1]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{#1}}{\filldraw[fill=printgray]}{\draw}}

\newcommand{\topborder}{\begingroup
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,6} {
  \alternatefill{\x} (\x, 6) +(0, 0.2) rectangle +(1, 1+0.2);
}
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\bottomborder}{\begingroup
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,6}
  \alternatexfill{\x} (\x, -1) +(0, -0.2) rectangle +(1, 1 - 0.2);
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\leftborder}{\begingroup
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,5}
  \alternatefill{\y} (0, \y) +(-0.2, 0) rectangle +(1 - 0.2,1);
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\rightborder}{\begingroup
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,5}
  \alternatexfill{\y} (7, \y) +(0.2, 0) rectangle +(1 + 0.2,1);
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\ring}{\begingroup
  \bottomborder
  \rightborder
  \topborder
  \leftborder
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\labelstop}{\begingroup
\def\pos{8}
\draw (0, \pos) +(0.3, -0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle a};
\foreach [count=\x] \c in {b,c, ..., g}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\label{\x + 1}
  \draw (\x, \pos) +(0.5, -0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle \c};
}
\draw (7, \pos) +(0.7, -0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle h};
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\labelsright}{\begingroup
\def\pos{8}
\draw (\pos, -1) +(0.5, 0.3) node {\strut\labelstyle 1};
\draw (\pos,  6) +(0.5, 0.7) node {\strut\labelstyle 8};
\foreach \x in {2,...,7}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xcoord{\x - 2}
  \draw (\pos,  \xcoord) +(0.5, 0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle \x};
}
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\labelsleft}{\begingroup
\def\pos{-0.2}
\draw (\pos, -1) +(-0.5, 0.3) node {\strut\labelstyle 1};
\draw (\pos,  6) +(-0.5, 0.7) node {\strut\labelstyle 8};
\foreach \x in {2,...,7}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xcoord{\x - 2}
  \draw (\pos,  \xcoord) +(-0.5, 0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle \x};
}
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\labelsbottom}{\begingroup
\def\pos{-1}
\draw (0, \pos) +(0.3, -0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle a};
\foreach [count=\x] \c in {b,c, ..., g}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\label{\x + 1}
  \draw (\x, \pos) +(0.5, -0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle \c};
}
\draw (7, \pos) +(0.7, -0.5) node {\strut\labelstyle h};
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\labels}{\labelsleft\labelsbottom\labelsright\labelstop}

\newcommand{\board}{
  \ring
  \innerboard
  \labels
  %% show origin
  \filldraw[fill=black] (0,0) circle [radius=1pt] +(0,-0.5) node{origin};
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\expandTeXnumber[1]{%
   % Delivers with trailing space the sequence of digit-tokens 
   % that comes from a TeX-number-quantity.
   % Be aware that with LaTeX-counters you need to use
   %   \value{counter}%
   % or
   %   \arabic{counter}%
   % in order to have a TeX-number-quantity.
   \expandafter\@firstofone\expandafter{\number#1} %
}%
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\introduceCoordinates{%
  \introduceCoordinatesInRange{1}{8}{1}{8}%
}%
\newcommand\introduceCoordinatesInRange[4]{%
  % #1 - lower bound for x-component
  % #2 - upper bound for x-component
  % #3 - lower bound for y-component
  % #4 - upper bound for y-component
  \introduceCoordinatesloop{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#1}{#3}%
}%
\newcommand\introduceCoordinatesloop[6]{%
  % #1 - to be incremented (lower) bound for x-component
  % #2 - upper bound for x-component
  % #3 - to be incremented (lower) bound for y-component
  % #4 - upper bound for y-component
  % #5 - lower bound for x-component
  % #6 - lower bound for y-component
  \ifnum\expandTeXnumber{#3}>\expandTeXnumber{#4}%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi{%
    \ifnum\expandTeXnumber{#1}>\expandTeXnumber{#2}%
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \fi{%
      %\message{\string%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \coordinate (\@alph{#1}#3) at %
      (%
        \ifnum\expandTeXnumber{#1}=\expandTeXnumber{#5}%
          \number\numexpr#1-1\relax.3%
        \else
          \ifnum\number\expandTeXnumber{#1}=\expandTeXnumber{#2}%
             \number\numexpr#1-1\relax.7%
           \else
             \number\numexpr#1-1\relax.5%
           \fi
        \fi
      ,%
        \ifnum\number\expandTeXnumber{#3}=\expandTeXnumber{#6}%
          -\number\numexpr#3-1\relax.7%
        \else
          \ifnum\expandTeXnumber{#3}=\expandTeXnumber{#4}%
            \number\numexpr#3-2\relax.7%
          \else
            \number\numexpr#3-2\relax.5%
          \fi
        \fi
      );%
      %}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\relax}{\introduceCoordinatesloop}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\number\numexpr#3+1\relax}{\introduceCoordinatesloop{#5}{#2}}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
    }%
  }%
}%

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\ring
\board
\introduceCoordinates
\draw[->,line width=2mm] (a1) -- (h1);
\draw[->,line width=2mm] (f2) -- (a2);
\draw[->,line width=2mm] (f3) -- (a3);
\draw[->,line width=2mm] (f4) -- (c4);
\draw[->,line width=2mm] (f5) -- (c5);
\draw[->,line width=2mm] (f6) -- (c6);
\draw[->,line width=2mm] (f7) -- (a7);
\draw[->,line width=2mm] (h8) -- (a8);
\draw[->,line width=2mm] (a1) -- (h8);
\draw[->,line width=2mm] (a8) -- (h1);
\draw[->,line width=2mm] (h7) -- (h2);
\draw[->,line width=2mm] (a4) -- (a6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow.  This works wonders.  It did allow the creation of the macro I wanted.  That is, `\newcommand{\arrow}[2]{{\draw[->,line width=2mm] (#1) -- (#2);}}` allows me to write simply `\arrow{a2}{h2}` and get an arrow from a2 to h2.  I gotta confess I don't understand any of the code written in `\introduceCoordinates`. :-)  Anyhow, thanks so much!

Comment: @user12406990 It is almost a miracle that the command name `\arrow` is not already used elsewhere. ;-) For the sake of TiKz-training I just started working on a second solution which makes use of TiKz's key-value-interface for making things customizable.  It may take some hours until I append that to my current answer.